# Instance variable vs method parameter

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an object, be it BookmarksManager. It handles the bookmarks saved in the server, manages updates etc.
One of the methods is called 'getNextPage(count, ???)' which fetches the next page of |count| bookmarks from the server. My question is, should I give it the parameter of the offset, form where I want to take the next page? Or should the offset be an instance variable and handle itself (after fetching it should increment by the number of fetched items)?

How should I decide, what should be the criteria?

Comment: This is up to you to decide, especially whether you want your class to be stateful or not. However, plainly on naming, the signatures should be `getNextPage()`, `getPage(num)` or `getItems(offset, numItems)`, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor that functionality into another class, say, BookmarksPaginator. That class is solely responsible for keeping information on which item it's currently in, just like an iterator. That means that class should be stateful and keep that number in its state. However, you would probably also want ask, in the constructor, how many items are on a page.

As a rule of thumb, when you have a SomethingManager in your code, it's a sign that it has too many responsabilities. Classes should have a single responsability whenever possible.

Comment: well, I have the BaseBookmarksManager, that has the getItems(count, cache) and getRefreshUpdates(lastUpdateDate), then, using composition I have the CachedBookmarksManager, that implements the same interface, only always checks, if there is something in the cache already, so no need to send any API request. Sometimes I want to use cache, sometimes not, so I use both. And finally I should make a bookmarkspaginator,that should contait a manager of choice (either base or cached), or how should I rename it, as you say it's breaking the single repsonsibility principle?

Comment: If I'm following correctly, it looks like your managers are assuming the responsability of dealing with pagination. If all of these classes have a single responsability, it seems like there's one concrete class more than you need. What I would do is have a BookmarksPaginator interface and two implemenations: a CachelessBookmarksPaginator and a CachedBookmarksPaginator. If the BaseBookmarksManager you described is a base class to be extended, I would call it just BookmarksPaginator and have a CachedBookmarksPaginator extending it. No need for managers then.

Comment: Also, the decision to use a interface or base class is one depending on whether you prefer not to use inheritance. Both are equally good and extendible. Inheritance seems like a better fit in this case, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a separate object for this. Something like:

```
class Paginator {
    private $currentPage;
    private $resultsPerPage = 20;
    private $numberOfResults = 0;
    private $object;

    public function __construct($object, $currentPage = 1) {
        $this->object = $object;
        $this->currentPage = is_numeric($currentPage) ? $currentPage : 1;

        $this->getNumberOfResults();
    }

    private function getNumberOfResults() {
        $this->numberOfResults = $this->object->count();
    }

    public function getPaginated()
    {
        $startFrom = $this->currentPage * $this->resultsPerPage - $this->resultsPerPage;
        return $this->object->getPaginated($startFrom, $this->resultsPerPage);
    }

    public function getNumberOfPages() {
        return floor($this->numberOfResults / $this->resultsPerPage);
    }

    public function getCurrentPage() {
        return $this->currentPage;
    }

    public function getNextPage() {
        return $this->currentPage < $this->getNumberOfPages() ? $this->currentPage + 1 : $this->currentPage;
    }
}

class BookmarksManager implements ManagerInterface {
    public function count() {
        // query here to get the number of bookmarks
    }

    public function getPaginated($startFrom, $numberOfResults) {
        // query here to get your bookmarks paginated by using
        // LIMIT $startFrom, $numberOfResults
    }
}

interface ManagerInterface {
    public function count();
    public function getPaginated($startFrom, $numberOfResults);
}
```

now you can use it like:

```
$bookmarkManager = new BookmarkManager();
$paginator = new Paginator($bookmarkManager, $_GET['page']);

$myBookmarks = $paginator->getPaginated();
$numberOfPages = $paginator->getNumberOfPages();
$currentPage = $paginator->getCurrentPage();
$nextPage = $paginator->getNextPage();
```

Please note that these classes are just an example.. You may modify them to comply with your needs